# Can ADT 17 be used to develop with SDK-2+ (Froyo/Ginderbread)?

Tags: android, adt, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

Is it okay to update ADT plugin to latest release ADT-17 preview, while developing for older SDKs like Froyo / Gingerbread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ADT supports developing across all API releases. Don't confuse the release version of the toolset (ADT) with the release version of the API.